# Instanceof type guard can't narrow the type of a variable used inside a callback

Tags: typescript

```
const userAPI = {
  async getById() { }
}

const batchedUpdates = (callback: () => any) => {
  callback();
}
const setError = (error: Error | null) => { }

async function main() {
  const result: { error: Error | null, data: any | null } = {
    error: null,
    data: null
  }
  try {
    const user = await userAPI.getById();
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      result.error = error;
      batchedUpdates(() => {
        setError(error);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Got error at the line of `setError(error)` statement:

> Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Error | null'.(2345)

I don't want to repeat the `instanceof` type guard in the callback of `batchedUpdates`, what's the right approach to handle this situation? Thanks.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwIIAUCSMC8MDeAUDDAIYQCeYwMA5olAEIWYAmAFAJQEwC+h-QqEiwARqSjAAFolYBVAA6sJiCLhjtgpADbbxwANYAuDdxwA+MmApnLRElt36DXANwCh4aDCRQAosjIIMjq7ChByCYBETAAPjBgcLq2PILkVDQAZnDUUACW4DAAtqR5YFwExDDC3siqSVAm+DDhwVGBwXEJSdoANDDKUKQmpNZdibp86vYkLR2R3bq9VSSDw4vaVfwkUMgUlbPVXrAIKOqkAO6lJ0hoWAB09EwsHJzuJLzVEtIarcjcMxIeUyv3mMDK0FGwEQIBB0WCAJWszqEAa9z+6j+70OMHEkhk8iUKgg7AqFgOOJIvnhyDC8zeSI+nCR2z4AiAA)

Comment: `setError(new Error(String(error)));` This is the best I could think of.

Comment: `setError(result.error);` will look better though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control Flow Analysis does not cross callback boundaries. This is explained in the canonical issue [Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)

A workaround is to use a local variable to freeze the type:

```
const userAPI = {
  async getById() { }
}

const batchedUpdates = (callback: () => any) => {
  callback();
}
const setError = (error: Error | null) => { }

async function main() {
  const result: { error: Error | null, data: any | null } = {
    error: null,
    data: null
  }
  try {
    const user = await userAPI.getById();
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      result.error = error;
      const localError = error
      batchedUpdates(() => {
        setError(localError);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwIIAUCSMC8MDeAUDDAIYQCeYwMA5olAEIWYAmAFAJQEwC+h-QqEiwARqSjAAFolYBVAA6sJiCLhjtgpADbbxwANYAuDdxwA+MmApnLRElt36DXANwCh4aDCRQAosjIIMjq7ChByCYBETAAPjBgcLq2PILkVDQAZnDUUACW4DAAtqR5YFwExDDC3siqSVAm+DDhwVGBwXEJSdoANDDKUKQmpNZdibp86vYkLR2R3bq9VSSDw4vaVfwkUMgUlbPVXrAIKOqkAO6lJ0hoWAB09EwsHJzuJLzVEtIarcjcMxIeUyv3mMDK0FGwEQIBB0WCAJWszqEAa9z+6j+70ORxEMG0IEc8JCeD+SJI4kkMnkShUEHYFQsBxxJF8xPYBKJ8ze5L4nCR2z4AiAA)